# Godox Umbrella Octa Softbox witgh speedlite bracket

Tags: studio-lighting, godox

I’m investing in my first off-camera lighting setup/softbox and wanted to check that the setup I have will all be together.

**Already owned**

- [Yongnuo YN560-IV Speedlite](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1101196-REG/yongnuo_yn_560iv_yn560_iv_speedlite.html)

- Trigger for the Yongnuo Speedlite

**Purchasing:**

- [Godox Umbrella Octa Softbox 120cm With Grid S-Type Mount](https://www.kayellaustralia.com.au/product/1085-godox-umbrella-octa-softbox-120cm-with-grid-s-type-mount)

- XLite 2.6m Black Single Lighting Stand (https://www.kayellaustralia.com.au/product/9380-xlite-2-6m-black-single-lighting-stand)

- [Neewer S-Type Bracket Holder with Bowens](https://www.amazon.com.au/gp/product/B01HZ4CHGS/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A23DLYW73200HP&psc=1)

My main concern is if everything will fit together and the weight capacity. Based on my research I think the answer is yes but I wanted to check with people that have used this type of equipment. I am also planning to take this setup to events so portability is another concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Godox is selling the softbox and S-mount combo, they should work together adequately. [1]

Technically the light stand looks adequate.

But to get more out of the light, a c-stand and a boom would be much better…and you will want a boom to get the light over your subject sooner or later. Then you’ll wish you had a boom sooner.

[1] the Godox s-bracket is not over engineered. It is a good place to start but it’s robustness is proportional to its price. It will get the job done but might not survive abuse during heavy use

Comment: Beyond that, they'll probably want something (i.e. sandbag or other type of weight) to anchor either type of stand if using it at events.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and I defiantly agree with the C stand and sandbag. I'll find an appropriate C stand for the main light but still get one of the stands for the rim light. I'm sure my local hardware store will have some sandbags/anchors.

Comment: @zaza the photo supply store will have sandbags that will work well for photography lighting. They are split to go over the legs of the stands.